# Error in deploying my node.js,express.js backend to netlify

Tags: node.js, express, hosting, netlify

I am trying to upload this api to netlify for days and have been unsuccessful.

This is my netlify/functions/api.js file

```
const express = require("express"); 
const app = express(); 
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); 
const postRoute = require("../../routes/post"); 
const commentRoute = require("../../routes/comment");
const getPostsRoute = require("../../routes/getPosts"); 
const getCommentsRoute = require("../../routes/getComments"); 
const morgan = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors= require('cors')
const dotenv = require("dotenv"); 
import serverless from 'serverless-http'; 

//netlify function

// exports.handler = async function (event , context) { 
//     return { 
//         statusCode: 200, 
//         body: JSON.stringify({message: "Hello World"}) , 
//     };
// };


dotenv.config(); 
mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

mongoose.connect( 
    process.env.MONGO_URL)
app.use(cors()); 
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api/post", postRoute);
app.use("/api/getPosts", getPostsRoute);

app.use("/api/comment", commentRoute); 
app.use("/api/getComments", getCommentsRoute);



app.listen(8800, () => { 
    console.log ("Backend server is running at port 8000"); 
})

export const handler = serverless(app);
```

This is my netlify.toml

```
[functions]
  external_node_modules = ["express"]
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
[[redirects]]
  force = true
  from = "/api/*"
  status = 200
  to = "/.netlify/functions/api/:splat"
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

I followed the netlify function docs but still couldn't figure out the way to correctly deploy the site.

Also, in the build command , i specified

```
node netlify/functions/api.js
```

and in the netlify functions directory, I specified

```
netlify/
```

There are just so many places where I could have made a error so I had to post for help.